# what is the underlying process of python multiprocess queue?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Does anyone explain the python multiprocessing queue communication in detail? What's happening when the parameter been put into the queue? I have a snippet of code, which is confusing me.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process


def task(queue_in, queue_out):
    mutural_np = np.zeros((10, 2))
    while True:
        msg = queue_in.get()
        res = []
        i = 0
        for i in range(msg):
            newnp = np.ones((1, 2)) * (msg - i)
            mutural_np[i:i+1] = newnp
        res = mutural_np[:i]
        print("===> put: ", res)
        queue_out.put(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue_in = Queue(10)
    queue_out = Queue(1)
    p1 = Process(target=task, args=(queue_in, queue_out))
    p1.start()
    for i in range(5):
        queue_in.put(i + 1)

    while True:
        msg = queue_out.get()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("***> out: ", msg)
```

and the output is:

```
===> put:  []
===> put:  [[2. 2.]]
===> put:  [[3. 3.]
 [2. 2.]]
***> out:  []
===> put:  [[4. 4.]
 [3. 3.]
 [2. 2.]]
***> out:  [[3. 3.]]
===> put:  [[5. 5.]
 [4. 4.]
 [3. 3.]
 [2. 2.]]
***> out:  [[4. 4.]
 [3. 3.]]
***> out:  [[5. 5.]
 [4. 4.]
 [3. 3.]]
***> out:  [[5. 5.]
 [4. 4.]
 [3. 3.]
 [2. 2.]]
```

why do I have this inconsistency?

I see the doc saying

> " When an object is put on a queue, the object is pickled and a background thread later flushes the pickled data to an underlying pipe. "

> "The pickle module keeps track of the objects it has already serialized so that later references to the same object won’t be serialized again"

From my understanding, the object is pickled and immutable when I put it in the queue, but it seems the pickling happens after it been flush out.

Comment: What happened when you tried reading the documentation? Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum; we can only help you understand something if you ask a *specific* question (and also demonstrate that you found the documentation, read the relevant section and still have reason to be confused), not just "how does this thing work?".

Comment: My question is why do I get this output from the code above which is inconsistent with the documentation. Thank you

Comment: What is your expected output? The documentation is talking about when you write a single complex object composed of other objects that may contain references to the same object multiple times, including circular references. In that situation it will recognize that one of the composed objects has already been serialized and will not needlessly re-serialize it again (or get into an endless loop when it's a circular reference). But if you write to the queue an object that was written to the queue on a *previous* write, it will be written out. What other choice is there?

Comment: Hey Booboo. I want to know why the values get from the queue are not the same as I put. Like the second put is [[2. 2.]], but I get [[3. 3.]]

Comment: I just saw your last comment. If you want to write a comment and be sure somebody is notified of it, you must start writing the user's name starting with a `@` character and then SO will autocomplete the name. So in my case you should have used `@Booboo` instead  of `Booboo`. Anyway, that's why it's always a good idea to specify what your expected output is; I had totally misunderstood what your question was about.

Comment: @Booboo D'accord, mercy beaucoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the answer by reading the source code.

When I put the object into the process queue, Python starts a thread to serialize and send the data. So, to be safe, do a copy before putting it in the queue.